# How to change the way HEX colors are shown in JetBrains' IDEs

Tags: settings, jetbrains-ide, color-scheme

Is it possible to change the way JetBrains' IDE's show colors? I'd wish to see the colors in my editor. At the moment the color picker is near the line number as shown below:

[image: As it is now]

I don't like the way it is now, all 'color texts' are gray. Is it possible to do something like this below? (or just make the text the color of the picked HEX):

[image: Just an example of how I want the highlighting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance | Show CSS color preview as background` option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Toggled it on, but it doesn't work yet (also rebooted the IDE)

Comment: Maybe it works only in plain CSS/SCSS/Sass/Less/Stylus and alike files but not in JSX or alike syntax (sorry, not a JavaScript person so do not have a code to test on). On another hand -- IDE shows colors in gutter area so it definitely recognizes them as CSS colors...

Comment: @Alpakash 1) What's your IDE and version? 2) Please try it using Default editor color scheme & light GUI theme (disable Material Theme UI plugin and restart IDE before that if you have it installed). I found one ticket that says that in does not work in custom scheme if certain condition is met.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne it worked out, it was the color schema indeed. It was on Material Oceanic. If I switch it (to most light themes) then it will do the trick. I now have it on All hallow's eve. I like darker theme's. Thanks for your help once again

Comment: @Alpakash So it must be that ticket then: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42428 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.